# extracting the time zones from the windows 7 clock

Tags: database, timezone

I have been demanded to go to the clock on windows 7 then to the "change time zone ..." box

and from the drop down list that will show to you after   clicking on the change time zone box , you will see different time zones ,i have to take these field exactly and inter it in the database , is there  a way to extract these filed to a file  ,, or to extract it to the database quickly

Comment: In what language???  In what database??

Comment: php . forgit databaSE . PUT IT IN A TEXT FILE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really had to do this from PHP, you could capture the output from the Windows command line command `tzutil /l`.  Or, you could [read from the Windows registry](http://phpmaster.com/access-the-windows-registry-from-php/) at the following location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.

But what would be the point?  PHP doesn't use Windows time zones. It uses IANA zones.  See [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) and the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Besides, once you put it in a text file or a database, you now just have a snapshot copy of it.  When Windows Update rolls out changes, you won't get them.